# Изучаю Javascript по курсу и возникла одна ошибка, написал точно как написал автор в видео, но у меня выдаёт ошибку. Поискал в интернете но не нашёл

Tags: javascript, javascript-events

Изучаю Javascript дома, скачал полный курс по Javascript[image: введите сюда описание изображения]. Написал точно так же как показано в видео, но у меня выдаёт ошибку. Пожалуйста объясните в чём может быть ошибка и как это исправить. Я думаю что версия javascript другая и правила тоже изменились, просто курс был записал 2018 года. Спасибо за внимание.[image: 1, код автора видео 2, моя и с ошибкой]

Comment: Перенести тег script куда-то в конец body, заработает. Браузер читает всё сверху вниз и когда запускает скрипт, запрашиваемый HTML элемент еще не существует.

Comment: Он находится с самом низу body. HTML и CSS файлы не я создавал, я их скачал уже готовыми который автор сам создал и ввёл всё это.

Comment: На 20й строке ошибка, к слову. И можно увидеть html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На 20 строчке scoreS

На 32 строчке не `querySelector('dice')`, а `querySelector('.dice')`

Comment: Наверное устал сильно, почти полчаса пересматривал но так и не нашёл. Спасибо вам огромное. После этого вылезла ещё одна ошибка в строке 34. У меня dice по номеровке 6 штук и нужно добавить их всех. Пишу таким образом (как автор написал и объяснил) но выдаёт ошибку что такого файл не найден. В чём может проблема?

Comment: Я так полагаю, вы выбираете число от 1 до 6 и добавляете его. У вас на 34 строчке ошибка. Вы не добавили 'dice' между 'dice-' и '.png'. Должно быть `'dice-' + dice + '.png'`  . Если вы уже исправили это, но ошибка остаётся, значит вы упустили момент, когда ведущий урока создавал файлы .png (на скриншоте видео они есть), у вас их просто нет.

Comment: Я в шоке от самого себя, как я мог этого не заметить, ещё и удивлялся что код не работает. Спасибо вам огромное